# How to calculate Sum of Count(*) in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that I count rows of them. For example;

```
Select count(*) FROM tbl_Events

Select count(*) FROM tbl_Events2
```

I need total count. How can I sum the result with a single statement?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
select sum(cnt) from (
    select count(*) as cnt from tbl_events
    union all
    select count(*) as cnt from tbl_events2
) as x
```

Comment: Change that to `union all`, otherwise you'll get incorrect results when both tables have the same number of records

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT (Select count(*) FROM tbl_Events) + (Select count(*) FROM tbl_Events2)
```

Or (tested in MSSQL), this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_Events 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT * FROM tbl_Events2) AS AllEvents
```

I'd guess the first will lead to better performance because it has more obvious index options. Test to be sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count(*)
From(
Select *    From tbl_Events
Union All
Select *    From tbl_Events2) as A
```